# FHIR Converter for Python

Tags: python, shopify, hl7-fhir, liquid-template

Is there is any function available in python to convert the given json input into HL7 FHIR format. By passing the Liquid Template (Shopify) and the input source data.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking that you are looking for something like [fhir.resources](https://pypi.org/project/fhir.resources/) library, where you can provide some dictionary with data to some kind of object that can be serialized.

```py
from fhir.resources.organization import Organization
from fhir.resources.address import Address

data = {
    "id": "f001",
    "active": True,
    "name": "Acme Corporation",
    "address": [{"country": "Switzerland"}]
}
org = Organization(**data)
org.resource_type == "Organization"
```

P.S. But don't quite follow why you mentioned Liquid Templates.